# define_method with super is causing infinite recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form builder subclass:

```
class ErrorHandlingFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

with the following code block:

```
helpers.each do |name|
  # We don't want to have a label for a hidden field

  # ERROR: The call to super below is actually calling itself and causing infinite recursion.
  #        How can I get it to call 
  next if name=="hidden_field"
  define_method name do |field, *args|
    options = args.detect {|argument| argument.is_a?(Hash)} || {}
    build_shell(field, options) do
      super(field,*args)
    end
  end
end
```

The `super` call is calling the method it's encapsulating code block is defining! This is causing infinite recursion and `Stack Level Too Deep`.

What I need is for it to call the method defined by the `name` variable in the form builder instance itself.

I just don't know how to refer to that instance. Even using `self.send` instead of `super` still causes the recursion.

Here is the code in its entirety, along with some logging I put in to track the stack:

```
class ErrorHandlingFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  helpers = field_helpers +
            %w(date_select datetime_select calendar_date_select time_select collection_select) +
            %w(collection_select select country_select time_zone_select) -
            %w(label fields_for)

  helpers.each do |name|
    # We don't want to have a label for a hidden field
    next if name=="hidden_field"

    define_method name do |field, *args|
      ErrorPrinter.print "name: #{name}"
      ErrorPrinter.print "field: #{field}"
      options = args.detect {|argument| argument.is_a?(Hash)} || {}
      build_shell(field, options) do
        super(field,*args)
      end
    end
  end

  def build_shell(field, options)

    # Capitalize the string, unless it's already been hardcoded.
    options[:label] = field.to_s.humanize.gsub(/^[a-z]|\s+[a-z]/) { |a| a.upcase } unless options[:label]

    options[:label].gsub!(/\w+/) { |word| CAPITALS.include?(word.upcase) ? word.upcase : word } 
    options[:label] += ":" unless options[:label].last==":"

    @template.capture do
      ErrorPrinter.print "Before"
      locals = {:element => yield, :label => label(field, options[:label] )}
      ErrorPrinter.print "After"

      if has_errors_on?(field)
        locals.merge!(:error => error_message(field, options))
        @template.render :partial => 'forms/field_with_errors', :locals => locals
      else
        @template.render :partial => 'forms/field', :locals => locals
      end
    end
  end

  def error_message(field, options)
    if has_errors_on?(field)
      errors = object.errors.on(field)
      errors.is_a?(Array) ? errors.to_sentence : errors
    else
      ''
    end
  end

  def has_errors_on?(field)
    !(object.nil? || object.errors.on(field).blank?)
  end

end
```

The recursion issue is with this line of `build_shell`:

```
  locals = {:element => yield, :label => label(field, options[:label] )}
```

as evidenced by the log:

```
XXXXXXXXX
name: collection_select
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb collection_select start
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb object: :review
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb method: :system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb collection: #<Set: {#<System id: 1, name: "Catalog"}>
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb value_method: :id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb text_method: :name
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb options: {:include_blank=>"Select a Standard", :label=>"System:", :object=>nil}
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb html_options: {:onchange=>"new Ajax.Request('/review/makes', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'post', parameters:Form.serialize('text')})"}
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb collection_select end
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb to_collection_select_tag start
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb collection: #<Set: {#<System id: 1, name: "Catalog"}>
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb value_method: id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb text_method: name
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb options: {:include_blank=>"Select a Standard", :label=>"System:"}
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb html_options: {:onchange=>"new Ajax.Request('/review/makes', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'post', parameters:Form.serialize('text')})"}
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb to_collection_select_tag end
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb options_from_collection_for_select start
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb collection: #<Set: {#<System id: 1, name: "Catalog"}>
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb value_method: :id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb text_method: :name
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb selected: {:selected=>nil, :disabled=>nil}
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
actionpack form_options_helper.rb options_from_collection_for_select end
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
End options_from_collection_for_select
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
name: label
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
field: system_id
XXXXXXXXX


XXXXXXXXX
Before
XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: `The super call is calling the method it's encapsulating code block is defining!` I don't believe that can be true. Can you share enough of the stack trace to show the recursive loop?

Comment: Please share `build_shell` code.

Comment: I know what you mean Wizard. but I put a print statement above the super call and it prints infinitely until the Stack Level Too Deep appears. Code added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, after 3 days. The recursion was taking place on the call to `label`. And if you look at the code:

```
helpers = field_helpers +
          %w(date_select datetime_select calendar_date_select time_select collection_select) +
          %w(collection_select select country_select time_zone_select) -
          %w(label fields_for)
```

That was not working. `label` and `fields_for` was not being removed from the array. They are present in `field_helpers` as symbols. But even marking them as symbols didn't work.

This code worked fine in Ruby 1.8.7, but wouldn't work in anything beyond. Obviously there is some change in modern version of Ruby that prevents declarations like the one above. I just decided to skip `label` and `fields_for` the same way I'm skipping `hidden_field`, and the code now works.